# Laravel - Route::redirect ('/') failed when I try in my server but work in local

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

my url redirection works perfectly locally but not at all on the servers, any idea ?
but if I manually write /en/home, the page works !
In routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('en/home');
});
```

or

```
Route::redirect('/', 'en/home');
```

Comment: Change your `return redirect('en/home');` into your view file `return view('home');` 'home' will be your blade file location

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are redirecting somewhere else `/en/home` when someone land on home page.

instead of redirecting user on /en/home you can return view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('your_view');
});
```

or if you want to redirect user to /en/home after landing on home page

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('en/home');
});



Route::get('{lang}/home', function ($lang) {
   return view("{$lang}/home");
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why my method works locally and not on a server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would make any difference, but you could try adding a `/` at the beginning of your redirect, so it'd be

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/en/home');
});
```

Alternatively, it could be that your routes are cached on your server.

You can clear the route cache by connecting to your server with SSH and running `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache.

If that doesn't work, I'd guess it must be some setting or configuration on your server causing the issue or overriding your route redirect somehow...